# Python script is not executed from my batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have written the following code within a `.bat` file, (to execute a python script):

```
conda activate 
cd OneDrive - My path/Documenti/Python/Seguridad/Remote 
py Seguridad_Python.py
```

If I execute that command in cmd.exe, the python file is executed.

But, if I run the `.bat` file with those commands, it opens the Command Prompt window, but does not execute the python script.

Can someone help?

I have also tried it with the next one, (everything in the same line), and it does the same.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\------ MY PATH --------\\Documenti\Python\Seguridad\Remote\Seguridad_Python.python
```

Comment: Had you made any attempt at using the search facility at the top of the page, you'd have very quickly seen the advice to use `call conda activate` from within a batch file. I would also advise that you double-quote your file and directory strings, and that Windows uses the backward slash as a file path separator, not the forward slash!

Comment: Okay, once again: Run in a Windows command prompt window `where conda` and there is output the fully qualified file name of the file with name `conda` which ends with the file extension `.cmd`. A batch file must __call__ another batch file with using the command `call` as written already by Compo. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for help on this command. I recommend to run also `cd /?` and read also the short usage help of this command. Run also `cmd /?` for the usage help of the Windows Command Processor which is the Windows command prompt and processing batch files.

Comment: `cd` is an internal command of `cmd.exe` as you can find out with `where cd` resulting in the output of an error message (hopefully as otherwise you have a problem with your Windows). `where py` shows you the fully qualified file name which is an executable. You better use in your batch file the fully qualified file name of `py.exe`. Then `cmd.exe` does not need to search for the file `py` in current directory and next in the directories of environment variable `PATH` with a file extension listed in environment variable `PATHEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `call` before was enough.

If I have the batch file and the python script at the same level, this was enough:

```
call conda activate 

call py Seguridad_Python.py
```

Comment: You weren't told to use `call` with `py`, just with `conda`. `py` is an `.exe` file, not a `.bat` or `.cmd` file, and therefore does not benefit from using the `call` command. You should have read and understood the comments, instead of misreading and/or misunderstanding them.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try as below. Specify the batch file extension in the command prompt. Once you hit enter, it invokes your python script and run the program

```
C:\Users\------ MY PATH --------\\Documenti\Python\Seguridad\Remote\xyz.bat
```